# Weird Error In Program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, gdb

I am new to programming, so when I got this error, I didn't know what to do. In my iPhone app, I press a button to switch a view, then I get this in the log.

GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-966) (Tue Mar 10 02:43:13 UTC 2009)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 880.
(gdb)

Help me understand what this means. Once this shows up, the application freezes up.

Comment: Perhaps posting your source code would help? It looks like you need to do some debugging. Try to isolate the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't an error message in and of itself, that's just the info text that means GDB (the GNU debugger) is being loaded. It probably means your app is throwing an uncaught exception. Is there anything *before* the bit you pasted here in the log?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I found the error and fixed it. Thanks for telling me about that. :)